# 404 error for ne0sight PPA on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, 17.10, ppa

I'm new to the Linux world. I installed the new Ubuntu 17.10 in a VM to study, and I am having a problem with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It produces these errors:

```
Atingido:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease Atingido:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Atingido:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu artful InRelease  
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu artful Release 404 Not Found
Obter:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78,6 kB] Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Ok farei isso obrigado

Comment: Again, please use English only. The problem however is easy to identify (the error message is English): the PPA you added - http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu - has no support for the current Ubuntu release. Remove it.

Answer (score 3):

[The PPA your error mentioned](https://launchpad.net/~ne0sight/+archive/ubuntu/chrome-gnome-shell) has no packages for Ubuntu 17.10,

Please remove the PPA if you have installed packages from it with this command:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell
```

or remove it from your sources with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again to check everything is fixed.